# OpenERP which addons directory to use?

Tags: migration, odoo, openerp-7

I had previously installed OpenERP on an Ubuntu 12 server and discovered we have two addons directories one located in `/opt/openerp/openerp-7.0-20131205-002453/openerp/addons/` and the other here `/opt/openerp/server/addons`.
I have then installed Ubuntu Server 14 and now see that the addons folder is located in `/usr/share/pyshared/openerp/addons`.

which addons directory do I use to migrate or which way to go about moving OpenERP from one server to another.

I'm new to this.

Comment: you can run server directly with addons path as option example ./openerp-server --addons-path path

Comment: for more commands check ./openerp-server --help it will show you other options such as port,db,etc..

Answer (score 0):

Use  ./openerp-server --addons-path urpath

For More options like port change use --help

Comment: A slightly correction: the correct option is --addons-path (note the -)